# How to take full path of a folder with a dialog in .NET MVC or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, folderbrowserdialog

i couldn't find any examples about folder dialog in mvc all of them in standart .net.
Is there a way to take full path of a folder with a dialog. No need to upload or select files inside that folder. I just need path.

Comment: The file dialog will not set any data unless a file is chosen.

Comment: i couldn't explain myself. i didn't want to say file dialog set something. File dialog didn't work for me because i need to select folder not file.

Comment: i couldn't find any examples about folder dialog in mvc all of them in standart .net

Comment: This has ZERO to do with .NET, this is all about browser behaviour (JavaScript/HTML). A browser's file dialog cannot return a folder, it can only select a file.

Comment: so, is there a way to do it with JavaScript or html?

Comment: No, there is not. There is no way to to this at all without writing a browser extension, which the user would have to voluntarily install. Servers really have no business looking at the user's local filesystem.

Comment: i did it with return fileresult thanks for help